# Can't build the MATIO library

Tags: c++, cmake, build, libraries, matio

So I have a project in which I must read structs from MAT files and save them with my C++ code, so I looked everywhere for a fitting library to use and so I came stumbled upon the MATIO library. Thing is, out of all the libraries I have used so far (eg. the Eigen library), I have to build this one. And this is the first time I do such a thing, so I looked up the documentation https://github.com/tbeu/matio#user-content-22-building-matio, but I can't seem to get CMake build it. I don't even know where to write these command lines from the documentation (see link), I only seem to be able to open cmake gui, with which I get the following error:

*Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "")
CMake Error at cmake/thirdParties.cmake:65 (message):
MAT73 requires HDF5
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:29 (include)*
*Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/RS3/Desktop/matio_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".*

Thing is, it says in the library's documentation that the HDF5 library is optional, so I didn't download it, but I still get this error. I really need to use this library, but I have been trying for the past 2 days to get it running, but I can't. What do I do now to finally get it built?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `HDF5` is probably required using the options you selected or perhaps the documentation on this is no longer up to date.

Comment: vcpkg may be an easy option to obtain this library if you are using msvc.